# Spring Kafka DefaultErrorHandler infinite loop

Tags: spring-kafka

Trying to create a non retry-able listener, on deserializataion error, it should just  print the suspect message as string and move on.

However, when explicitly setting the DefaultErrorHandler (in an effort to see msg/payload body), it goes into a retry loop. Without setting it, it just prints the exception msg (expected string but got null) and moves on.

I've tried setting Backoff with 0 retries with no luck. Also I'm still unable to see the contents of the suspect message.

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaListenerCAFMessageContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(getCafKafkaConfig());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setConcurrency(consumerConcurrency);
        DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
            // trying to print the payload that doesn't serialize
            LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage() + record.value().toString()); // but record.value() is always null
        });

    @org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener(topics = "gcrs_process_events", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerCAFMessageContainerFactory")
    public void listenCafMsgs(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record, Acknowledgment ack) {...}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The value has to be null so that the deserializer is type safe - for example, if you are using the `JsonDeserializer` to convert `byte[]` to a `Foo` - it is not type safe if it returns a record with a `byte[]` payload.

See the `cause` of the `ListenerExecutionFailedException` - it is a `DeserializationException` which has the `data` field.

```java
/**
 * Get the data that failed deserialization (value or key).
 * @return the data.
 */
public byte[] getData() {
    return this.data; // NOSONAR array reference
}
```